# Transforming curl request job in failure/success in jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins

I'm running a curl command in jenkins, but independently of the results, jenkins always turns the job in a success.

How can I turn the job status in success/failure depending on the curl result?

This is my curl request inside a execute shell block from jenkins:

```
curl -X GET http://api...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, curl returns 0 exit code regardless of what happens with the request by default. You turn the job status into failure in jenkins by returning a non-zero exit code. You can achieve this in curl using the --fail option. Whenever curl sees a non-200 level http response, it returns a 22 exit status. Check it out:

```
~ % curl --silent --fail http://httpstat.us/200 > /dev/null; echo $?
0
~ % curl --silent --fail http://httpstat.us/401 > /dev/null; echo $?
22
~ % curl --silent --fail http://httpstat.us/500 > /dev/null; echo $?
22
```

Some caveats at https://superuser.com/questions/590099/can-i-make-curl-fail-with-an-exitcode-different-than-0-if-the-http-status-code-i.